# WCF proxy Client Singleton Pattern Performance

Tags: .net, wcf, performance, basichttpbinding

Is it better, performance wise, to design a Proxy Client in WCF with singleton pattern, or each time create the object and close it after the call?

Answer (score 2):

Depends.  We had this problem recently and because we were needing to make a call every few seconds or less it made more sense to keep one instance of the proxy client and keep making the call.  If the client/connection faulted, I just recreated the proxy client.

What was happening before is I had created a new proxy each call and closed the connection.  Apparently the GC wasn't cleaning these up fast enough and memory was piling up.

I think it depends on how often you're calling the service.

Comment: I agree with @MarkW - I tend to use a singleton pattern for frequent service calls.